# How to fix the error in my Browse for file & Copy Paste Formula for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, I was able to find separate codes and put them together but I am having some difficulties on finding a code that will help me get my expected results. 
Basically, I wanted a Macro tool that will allow me to browse for the filename of an excel file and copy all active rows starting Row 5 and paste values on Col A:J except for the header so paste will start in Row 2.

I have found separate VBA codes for the functions/ requirements based on my requirement but the problem is everytime I try to add them on my existing code it results to an error.

```
Sub GetFile()

'Browse for File

Dim fileNameAndPath As Variant
fileNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If fileNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

'Open the File

Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileNameAndPath

'Close the File

Workbooks.Close Filename:=fileNameAndPath

'Copy Data

Set range_to_copy = Worksheets("Report").Rows("5:1000")

'Paste Data

Set range_for_pasting = Workbooks("Macro Manual IHB.xlsm").Worksheets("CashPositionReport").Range("A2:J")

range_to_copy.Copy
range_for_pasting.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End Sub

Errors are on these codes:

'Close the File

Workbooks.Close Filename:=fileNameAndPath

'Paste Data

Set range_for_pasting = Workbooks("Macro Manual IHB.xlsm").Worksheets("CashPositionReport").Range("A2:J")
```

The close the File code doesn't work at all
But the Paste data works if I try to use .Range("A2") instead of the above but it  overrides the formula that I have in Col K:Q

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: `Range("A2:J")` - `"A2:J"` is not a valid range reference. You need a row number for J.

Comment: Also, it's `Workbook.Close`, not `Workbooks.Close`, so you need a valid `Workbook` object.

Comment: Hi BigBen Thank you for your help. I've tried to update the Range to ("A2:J2") but still having an error. Can you please help recommend what can use. Can I use Col instead of Range?

Comment: Oh my bad. Ignore part of my previous comment. You just need to remove the `J`. You can pastespecial into one cell, namely `A2`.

Comment: But your real issue is that you're copying entire rows -  `Worksheets("Report").Rows("5:1000")` - and you probably don't need to do that. Why not `Range("A5:J1000")` instead of `Rows("5:1000")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the back-and-forth in comments:

1) You can `PasteSpecial` into a single cell, `A2`. Your problem is that you are copying entire rows: `Set range_to_copy = Worksheets("Report").Rows("5:1000")` when you probably only need `Range("A5:J1000")`. Pasting an entire row will overwrite any formulas you have in columns to the right of J.

2) It is [`Workbook.Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close), not `Workbooks`. So you need to work with a valid `Workbook` object. Something like this:

```
Dim wb as Workbook    
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=fileNameAndPath)

wb.Close ' no need for FileName, the workbook already has a fileName
```